# Multiple .evaluate calls, XPath Java

Tags: java, xpath

I have a list of XPath expressions with common path prefixes. For example, I might have something like:

```
Elements/Bills/Amount/USD
Elements/Id
```

What I want to do is first get all the Elements nodes, then, for a given node, check if it contains the two data points I want (I need to check each node, starting from the top). Something like `node.get(/Bills/Amount/USD), node.get(/Id)` would be perfect. However, after compiling and executing `Elements`(`xPath.compile(Elements).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);)`I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `node` into the subsequent calls to `evaluate()`. The first call was using the doc as the "context" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256199(v=vs.110).aspx) which means the root of the xml doc was considered the context (basically where the search starts from).

Once I had a node I just passed that in with the remainder of the path for my next call to `evaluate()`.

The first call ( returned the list of `Elements`):

```
xPath.compile("Elements").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```

The second call (returned all `USD` elements that are children of the current `Element` node):

```
xPath.compile("./Bills/Amount/USD").evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODESET)
```